# Hot to pass BuildContext inside the RetryPolicy Interceptor

Tags: flutter, dart, interceptor

I need to create an interceptor that whenever my API response is 401, I need to refresh the token with the refreshToken. And if something goes wrong, I need to redirect the user to the LoginPage.

But I'm having some difficulties on passing the BuildContext inside the refreshToken method... I'm using the http_interceptor dependency.

```
class AuthedApiClient {
  http.Client client = InterceptedClient.build(
    interceptors: [AuthorizationInterceptor()],
    requestTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
  );

 static Future<void> refreshToken(BuildContext context) async {
    LoginService loginService = LoginService();
    try {
      loginService.refreshLogin();
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is RefreshTokenException) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: e.message,
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
          timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
          textColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: ThemeColors.errorToastMessage,
          fontSize: 12.0,
        );
      }
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');
    }
  }
}
class AuthorizationInterceptor implements InterceptorContract {
  Logger logger = Logger();

  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({required RequestData data}) async {
    logger.v(
        "Requisição para: ${data.baseUrl}\nCabeçalhos: ${data.headers}\nCorpo: ${data.body}");
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var token = prefs.getString('token');
      data.headers.clear();
      data.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ${token!}';
      data.headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
      data.headers['Client'] = 'CustomerApp';
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e(e);
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({required ResponseData data}) async {
    return data;
  }
}

class ExpiredTokenRetryPolicy extends RetryPolicy {
  @override
  Future<bool> shouldAttemptRetryOnResponse(ResponseData response) async {
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      await AuthedApiClient
          .refreshToken(); //I need to somehow pass the context to this guy here...
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes we might not be able to get current `context` in our app wherever we need, in those cases, We should consider using Global Context.

For using Global Context, What we need to do is:

create a `class` like this:

```
class AppSettings {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorState = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

Now, inside your `MaterialApp` give navigatorKey as:

```
navigatorKey: AppSettings.navigatorState,
```

Now, to get the BuildContext inside your `refreshToken` function, you don't need to define `context` as parameter.

Replace this `Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/');` by:

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(AppSettings.navigatorState.currentContext!, '/');
```

And you're done.

Comment: This answer saved my day.